# Delete row from grid and database with Kendo UI and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using a MVC project with Visual Studio 2012 and Kendo UI 2014.

I **can delete a row from the grid** and it disappears, but when I reload the page, the row that I deleted re-appears. **I would like to remove from the database too.**

This is my code:

**.cshtml (View):**

```
<div class="grid">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<UsersModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(r => r.Action("GetAccounts", "ManagerAccounts", new { area = "Admin" }))
        .Model(r => r.Id(p => p.Id))
        .Destroy("Delete", "ManagerAccounts")
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id);
        columns.Bound(c => c.UserName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Email);
        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(120);
    })
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(true)
        .ButtonCount(5)
    )
    .Scrollable()
    .Sortable()
    .Navigatable()
)
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Everis.WebApps.Security.Models.ListadoUsuarioModel users)
{
    if (users != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        AccountRepository.DeleteUsuarios(users.Id);
    }

    return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
}
```

**Repository (AccountRepository):**

```
protected ApplicationDbContext Context = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public void DeleteUsuarios(string id)
    {
        var usuario = this.Context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (usuario != null)
        {
            this.Context.Users.Remove(usuario);                
        }
    }
```

**IdentityModels (from ApplicationDbContext Context):**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRol : IdentityRole
{
    public Application Application { get; set; }
}

public class Application
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {            
    }

    public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }

    public new DbSet<ApplicationRol> Roles { get; set; }

}
```

Any idea to delete from database too?

Comment: this.Context.Users.DeleteObject(usuario); this.Context.SaveChanges(); you can try this code if your are using Entity framework for DB operation

Comment: DeleteObject and SaveChanges don't exists

Comment: What is the this.Context?

Comment: protected ApplicationDbContext Context = new ApplicationDbContext();

Comment: From which class ApplicationDbContext is drived??

Comment: from IdentityModels.cs

Comment: are you using Entity framwork?can you post the code of class ApplicationDbContext?

Comment: there should be a method SaveChanges() in this.Context. if this this.Context is object of ApplicationDBContext see the url http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457075%28v=vs.111%29.aspx

Comment: and for delete from DB?

Comment: Yes it will delete from DB . you just have do after the line this.Context.Users.Remove(usuario); write this.Context.SaveChanges()

Comment: Thanks, now it works!, I use this.Context.SaveChanges(); and with this it delete from DB. Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/682113/Extending-Identity-Accounts-and-Implementing-Rol, you can check this url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [this url](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/682113/Extending-Identity-Accounts-and-Implementing-Rol).

```
this.Context.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: Can you see my other answer please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383893/update-rows-from-grid-and-database-with-kendo-ui-and-mvc I have the same problem but with update and with that doesn't work.

Comment: added my answer over there.