# Update rows from grid and database with Kendo UI and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using a **MVC project** with **Visual Studio 2012 and Kendo UI 2014.**

I **can update a row from the grid** and it changes, but when I reload the page, the row appears with the original info. I would like to **update it in the database too**.

This is my code:

**.cshtml (View):**

```
<div class="grid">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<UsersModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(r => r.Id(p => p.Id))
        .Read(r => r.Action("GetAccounts", "ManagerAccounts", new { area = "Admin" }))
        .Destroy("Delete", "ManagerAccounts")
        .Update("Update", "ManagerAccounts")
        .Create("Create", "ManagerAccounts")
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id);
        columns.Bound(c => c.UserName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Email);
        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(120);
    })
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(true)
        .ButtonCount(5)
    )
    .Sortable()
    .Navigatable()
    .ToolBar(toolbar => {
        toolbar.Create();
        toolbar.Save();        
    })
)
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, IEnumerable<UsersModel> users)
{
    if (users != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            AccountRepository.UpdateUsuarios(user);
        }
    }

    return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
}
```

**Repository (AccountRepository):**

```
public void UpdateUsuarios(UsersModel user)
{
    var usuario = this.Context.Users.Where(l => l.Id == user.Id).FirstOrDefault();

    if (usuario != null)
    {
        usuario.Id = user.Id;
        usuario.UserName = user.UserName;
        usuario.Email = user.Email;
        this.Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I tried with `this.Context.SaveChanges();` but it doesn't work.

Comment: does value update in database?

Comment: what is `this` in your update method. One more thing you use entity framework or link.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this code:

```
if (usuario != null)
{
    usuario.Id = user.Id;
    usuario.UserName = user.UserName;
    usuario.Email = user.Email;
    this.Context.Entry(usuario).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    this.Context.SaveChanges();  // Or you may try await this.Context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```